# Mapping special null constant values into DBNull in a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow, xtragrid

I'm working with an existing object framework that uses special values to represent NULL for primitives int, DateTime, long. Data containing these values are added to a DataTable and displayed in third-party controls such as XtraGrid.

All is fine, except when aggregates are applied to the data. In this case, obviously the special values are processed instead of the NULL entries.

So I think the best solution is to map the values to/from DBNull when putting into the DataRow. I thought about subclassing the DataTable and DataRow, but the base classes don't allow overriding of the accessors.

I could add extra Get/Set functions to the subclasses but this relies on remembering to use them. I could add static helper functions instead of subclassing, but this has the same problem.

Is there a more elegant solution?

**Update**
It's the grid itself that is doing the aggregation, as it has flexible controls to let the user define summaries at run-time. So I think the only real solution is to map to/from DBNull somehow, just looking for an elegant way of doing this.

Comment: How do you read the data? Are you able to use IDataReader for filling the dataset?

Comment: The data comes from a custom server call and is populated manually using AddRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create an extension method to help you fill the datatable and convert values to dbnull:

```
public static class DataExtensions
{
    public static DataRow AddRow(this DataRowCollection rowCollection, params object[] values)
    {
        object[] newValues = new object[values.Length];

        for(int i=0;i<values.Length;i++)
        {
            object value = values[i];
            if (value != null)
            {                    
                Type t = value.GetType();
                //check for min value only for value types...
                if (t.IsValueType)
                {
                    //maybe you can do some caching for that...
                    FieldInfo info = t.GetField("MinValue",
                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static
                        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
                        );
                    if (info != null)
                    {
                        object o = info.GetValue(null);
                        if (value.Equals(o))  //very important == will return false
                        {
                            value = DBNull.Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            newValues[i] = value;               
        }

        return rowCollection.Add(newValues);
    }
}
```

And then you will be able to write something like:

```
t.Rows.AddRow(a,b,c,d,e);
```

Comment: This is the approach I have gone for - adding GetColumnValue(), SetColumnValue() extension methods to the DataRow.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can create conditional aggregates with IIF like (silly example):

```
        DataTable t= new DataTable();
        t.Columns.Add("id");
        t.Columns.Add("id2");
        t.Columns.Add("id3", typeof(int), "IIF(id="+int.MinValue.ToString()+",id2,id+id2)");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            t.Rows.Add(new object[] { i, 2 * i });
        }

        t.Rows.Add(new object[] { int.MinValue, 2000});
```

Edit: adapted to your comment on other post.

Comment: This is a possibility I guess, but would mean doubling up all columns (except strings).

Comment: Well, I didn't mean to double columns, I only thought your problem was with aggregates and my proposal was to modify the aggregate functions.

Comment: Ok apologies, I see, actually it's the grid control itself that does the aggregation (which is why the values are incorrectly processed). I'll add clarification to the question.